# Deploying an eventmachine based rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eventmachine

When deploying a rails web app locally I start a thin server at port 3000 and the EventMachine listens to websocket requests at 8080 but how would this be deployed to Heroku or are there any other Backend services that would suit this app?
This is the code that starts the Eventmachine loop

```
EM.run {
  EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen { |handshake|
    puts "WebSocket connection open"

    # Access properties on the EM::WebSocket::Handshake object, e.g.
    # path, query_string, origin, headers

    # Publish message to the client
    ws.send "Hello Client, you connected to #{handshake.path}"
    }

    ws.onclose { puts "Connection closed" }

    ws.onmessage { |msg|
    puts "Recieved message: #{msg}"
    ws.send "Pong: #{msg}"
    }
  end
```

Comment: this is a very broad question. What kind of hosting in production will you be using? although Thin is not really recommended for production hosting but it does use Eventmachine internally, so you might not need to also run a separate EM server.

Comment: @maniacalrobot But when i use the same port i get an error
'Port already in use'
Is there a workaround for that.

Comment: What are you running in the event machine that requires it listen in a port?

Comment: @maniacalrobot 
 
It listens to websocket requests from the client

Comment: I switched to faye-websockets that allows listening to websockets in the same port used by the app server by defining a Rack middleware

Comment: I've used this article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets  to setup a website that includes a a fate server running a web socket layer. This basically installs a rack middlewear that detects if the incoming data is from the we socket, allowing you to run both http and web socket using the same port. It's not recommended in a high volume production setup, but it does work.